# TestCafe with API tests not running

Tags: javascript, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

When we try to run the sample API tests testcafe not running those tests, earlier we used to run those tests but not some reason they are not running.

Error throwing
 `TypeError: t.request is not a function`

Code snippet:

```
`fixture("request");
test("User API", async (t) => {
    const results = await t.request({
        url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
        method: "GET",
    });
    await t
    .expect(results.status).eql(200)
    .expect(results.statusText).eql('OK')
});
```

API tests should without throwing that error, They are used to work before.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce the issue. Please share the TestCafe versions you use.

Comment: Current version that I am using 1.11.0 and node version 16

Answer (score 0):

API testing was implemented only in the 1.20.0 TestCafe version. You need to update TestCafe.